# Get intersection elements of nested dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

Let's say I have a list of dicts.
For example, the list contains the following dicts:

```
{'david': {'status': 'available', 'type': 'human, 'location': [2, 3, 4]}, 'kuka': {'type': 'robot'}}

{'david': {'status': 'available', 'location': [2, 3, 4]}, 'kuka': {'status': 'available', 'type': 'robot'}}
```

(The nesting level is not fixed)

As a result, I want to have:

```
{'david': {'status': 'available', 'location': [2, 3, 4]}, 'kuka': {'type': 'robot'}}
```

As a result, I want to have dict, which contains common elements, which are existing in both dicts, not only the keys.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: To be honest - no clue so far...still trying to figure something out...

Comment: Is it possible that the same key exists in both dicts, but with a different value?  If so, what would you like to do in this case?

Comment: It should not happen. However, if this might happen, raising an error would be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can recursively iterate over all dictionary keys.  The most compact way of writing this is probably

```
def common_items(d1, d2):
    return {k: common_items(d1[k], d2[k]) if isinstance(d1[k], dict) else d1[k]
            for k in d1.viewkeys() & d2.viewkeys()}
```

I'd recommend to spell the dictionary comprehension out to a for loop to make the code more readable, and allow to raise an error in case there are differing values:

```
def common_items(d1, d2):
    result = {}
    for k in d1.viewkeys() & d2.viewkeys():
        v1 = d1[k]
        v2 = d2[k]
        if isinstance(v1, dict) and isinstance(v2, dict):
            result[k] = common_items(v1, v2)
        elif v1 == v2:
            result[k] = v1
        else:
            raise VallueError("values for common keys don't match")
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what you mean by 'intersection'. 
If you want to get the common attributes of each dictionary item, you can use a `set` to get all common keys with following codes.

```
common_keys = reduce(set.intersection, [set(i.keys()) for i in d.values()])
```

Then you can iterate over the dictionary to filter the common keys and values.

Comment: Maybe intersection was the wrong word. The result should not be a set, which gives me the information in which keys there are common key, value pairs, I want to have the common elements returned as a dict.

Comment: Eljobso, after applying Neo X's advice, it is quite simple to write a function which appends the value in each dictionary for each key in the set you created to a list. Then you add the resulting list of values to a dictionary with that same key. Return the resulting dictionary at the end.

Answer (score 0):

i have worked out a full solution for deep intersection

```
def common_items_dict(d1, d2, use_set_for_list_commons=True, use_set_for_dict_key_commons=True, append_empty=False):
    result = {}
    if use_set_for_dict_key_commons:
        shared_keys=list(set(d1.keys()).intersection(d2.keys())) # faster, order not preserved
    else:
        shared_keys=common_items_list(d1.keys(), d2.keys(), use_set_for_list_commons=False)

    for k in  shared_keys:
        v1 = d1[k]
        v2 = d2[k]
        if isinstance(v1, dict) and isinstance(v2, dict):
            result_dict=common_items_dict(v1, v2, use_set_for_list_commons, use_set_for_dict_key_commons, append_empty)
            if len(result_dict)>0 or append_empty:
                result[k] = result_dict 
        elif isinstance(v1, list) and isinstance(v2, list):
            result_list=common_items_list(v1, v2, use_set_for_list_commons, use_set_for_dict_key_commons, append_empty)
            if len(result_list)>0 or append_empty:
                result[k] = result_list 
        elif v1 == v2:
            result[k] = v1
    return result

def common_items_list(d1, d2, use_set_for_list_commons=True, use_set_for_dict_key_commons=True, append_empty=False):
    if use_set_for_list_commons: 
        result_list= list(set(d2).intersection(d1)) # faster, order not preserved, support only simple data types in list values
        return result_list

    result = []
    for v1 in d1: 
        for v2 in d2:
            if isinstance(v1, dict) and isinstance(v2, dict):
                result_dict=common_items_dict(v1, v2, use_set_for_list_commons, use_set_for_dict_key_commons, append_empty)
                if len(result_dict)>0 or append_empty:
                    result.append(result_dict)
            elif isinstance(v1, list) and isinstance(v2, list):
                result_list=common_items_list(v1, v2, use_set_for_list_commons, use_set_for_dict_key_commons, append_empty)
                if len(result_list)>0 or append_empty:
                    result.append(result_list)
            elif v1 == v2:
                result.append(v1)
    return result


def deep_commons(v1,v2, use_set_for_list_commons=True, use_set_for_dict_key_commons=True, append_empty=False):
    """
    deep_commons
     returns intersection of items of dict and list combinations recursively

    this function is a starter function, 
    i.e. if you know that the initial input is always dict then you can use common_items_dict directly
    or if it is a list you can use common_items_list directly

    v1 - dict/list/simple_value
    v2 - dict/list/simple_value
    use_set_for_dict_key_commons - bool - using set is faster, dict key order is not preserved 
    use_set_for_list_commons - bool - using set is faster, list values order not preserved, support only simple data types in list values
    append_empty - bool - if there is a common key, but no common items in value of key , if True it keeps the key with an empty list of dict

    """

    if isinstance(v1, dict) and isinstance(v2, dict):
        return common_items_dict(v1, v2, use_set_for_list_commons, use_set_for_dict_key_commons, append_empty)
    elif isinstance(v1, list) and isinstance(v2, list):
        return common_items_list(v1, v2, use_set_for_list_commons, use_set_for_dict_key_commons, append_empty)
    elif v1 == v2:
        return v1
    else:
        return None


needed_services={'group1':['item1','item2'],'group3':['item1','item2']}
needed_services2={'group1':['item1','item2'],'group3':['item1','item2']}

result=deep_commons(needed_services,needed_services2)

print(result)
```